# Multiple facebook accounts in single iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook, accounts

Is there a way I can allow user to login with multiple facebook accounts at the same time? Like what tweetie2 does for twitter accounts. So if I have two facebook accounts - a@a.com and b@b.com. I want the user to login with both of them on my iPhone app. Selecting tab for a@a.com will show statuses from a and selecting tab b@b.com would do the same for b.

Please let me know.
Thanks
AJ

Answer (score 2):

Ya if you used keychain to store their credentials it'd be possible to have them enter their credentials for each account (you'd store them in keychain) and then do the logout/login as necessary.  Not the best, but might be all you have open to you.

Answer (score 1):

With the way the FBConnect code works, probably not more than one user at a time.

However, if you had two users A and B, when user B's tab is clicked on, you could log out user A and then log in user B. Then, when user A's tab is clicked on, user B would be logged out and user A logged back in.

Sam

Comment: Thans for your response. But i think the way it works is, when a user logs out, the only way to log him in is showing the FBDialog for him to enter credentials. Dont think it would allow that to happen automatically storing the credentials may be in NSUserDefaults or KeyChain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one in iPhone app and the other web based

Unfortunately the web based version does not support photo uploads.  You have to use the app version to get this.

Answer (score 0):

There is 'Friendly' for facebook on the iPad so it must be possible.